# How to reference UITableViewController from a UITableViewCell class?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, swift, uikit

I have the following:

1. UITableViewController
2. UITableView
3. Custom UITableViewCell subclass

I used a .xib file for the cell, which is a `CustomCell` subclass. This custom cell handles IBActions for some touch events on the cell's buttons.

I'd like to reference the ViewController and some of its variables from the cell.

How am I supposed to access the UITableViewController from the UITableViewCell class?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I wouldn't create this kind of dependency between the cell and the view controller - that makes the architecture more intricate and the cell not reusable.

I suggest you to use the delegation pattern, which may sound a little complicated - although you're already using (`UITableViewDelegate` is a typical example):

- create a protocol `MyCellProtocol` with one method `didTapCell`, accepting a `UITableViewCell` and/or some custom data you want to pass to the view controller
- create a public delegate property in your custom cell: `weak var cellDelegate: MyCellProtocol?`
- in the `didTapXXX` handler or `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` of your cell, call `self.cellDelegate?.didTapCell()`, passing the expected parameters
- in your view controller, implement the `MyCellProtocol`
- in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` of your view controller, when creating/dequeuing the cell, set its `cellDelegate` property to `self`

At this point, when a tap is done in your cell, the `didTapCell` method of the view controller is called, and from there you can do whatever you need to achieve.

The key point is: rather than making the cell handle the cell tap/selection, notify the view controller and let it do the job.

Comment: The second bullet above appears to be for Objective-C.  In swift one might do this:  let delegate: ClasThatImplementsProtocol

Comment: This may work. But when encapsulating the dataSource to a different class, as you should (dont put the DS into the controller), you need to find a different way of connecting cells and controller. One thing you could do is to use the tableView delegate method willDisplayCell to assign the tableview as a delegate to the cell. You then need to unlink them in prepareForReuse and dealloc or deinit depending on which language you are using. Notifications also not the ideal solution if there multiple controllers active that listen to the same notification.

Comment: thank you very much, I know it 's spam but you save my day ;) good luck

Comment: it would be great if you provide some code in the answer :) @Antonio

Comment: Just got to say thank you so much. Sorted me out. If anyone would like more info on Delegates and Protocols watch this great short video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DBWu6TnhLeY

Comment: Won't it create a reference cycle like: controller -> collection view -> cell -> controller?

Comment: Thanks @Ivan, yes you're right, the delegate should be `weak`, just updated the answer.

Answer (score 28):

```
extension UIView {
    var parentViewController: UIViewController? {
        var parentResponder: UIResponder? = self
        while parentResponder != nil {
            parentResponder = parentResponder!.next
            if let viewController = parentResponder as? UIViewController {
                return viewController
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Inside your cell

```
if let myViewController = parentViewController as? MyViewController {
    print(myViewController.title)
}
```

Comment: I wanted to perform a segue from a uicollectionviewcell nested inside a uitableviewcell and this worked perfectly!. Thanks.

Comment: Worked in the Master Detail project template. Thank you.

Comment: in Swift 4, `.nextResponder()` is changed to `.next`

Answer (score 14):

I don't think you should do that and probably you're doing something wrong but if you really-really need it then just have a property in your `CustomCell` class.

```
weak var viewController : UIViewController
```

then when you create the cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` set the property

```
cell.viewController = self
```

after that you can easily access the view controller from within the cell code:

```
self.viewController.doSomething()
```

But again, in my opinion, you should redesign your code. The cell should not care about the controller. It should care only about displaying itself and nothing else

Comment: > "The cell should not care about the controller. It should care only about displaying itself and nothing else"


Does it mean that it is also bad practice to add buttons in a custom cell if the button's action would be to access or change some model property? Because in that case the model can accessed only from the controller since it is the source of the table view...

Comment: it is not of course. a bad practice would be to have code which processes a lot of model's stuff in the button's action. a good practice in this case is to have just one line of code in the button's action. the line should post a notification or call a delegate method. and then the controller should react on this call or this notification and run all the needed code. controller, not  the cell. i hope you understand what i'm talking about

Comment: in most UI frameworks its very common to access the container of the object, for example in ActionScript you can call the parent using this.parent, and from my experience in Apple language it seems Apple is not experienced enough with visual programming language, so i guess this solution is very acceptable and clever and i will give it +1

Comment: I think defining the ViewController as weak inside cell might be better.

Comment: @MuhammedGül absolutely true. Thank you for pointing this out

Answer (score 6):

add Extension

```
 extension UITableViewCell {

        var viewControllerForTableView : UIViewController?{
            return ((self.superview as? UITableView)?.delegate as? UIViewController)
        }

    }
```

now downCast as below

```
   if let viewController = self.viewControllerForTableView as? AnyController{

       print(viewController.variable)

   }
```

.

Comment: "Cannot find type 'AnyController' in scope"

Comment: @ElKePoN AnyController is a dummy name of the controller class you want to typecast.

Answer (score 2):

Best way is to implement Delegation. Your delegate will inform the view controller about the button click. And, In turn your view controller (who is conforming the protocol for above delegate) will handle the task that you want to perform on click event. (Delegation pattern tutorials are available online. you can go through them if you want to know how to do delegation).

Answer (score 1):

Read the other comments about really wanting to use an alternate approach before trying this, but using this extension will allow you to get to the `dataSource` and `delegate` both of which should be the `UITableViewController`

```
extension UITableViewCell {
    var tableView:UITableView? {
        get {
            for var view = self.superview ; view != nil ; view = view!.superview {
                if view! is UITableView {
                    return (view! as UITableView)
                }
            }
            return nil
        }
    }

    var tableViewDataSource:UITableViewDataSource? {
        get {
            return self.tableView?.dataSource
        }
    }

    var tableViewDelegate:UITableViewDelegate? {
        get {
            return self.tableView?.delegate
        }
    }
}
```