# Perform segue from a UITableViewCell class to a view controller

Tags: uitableview, uicollectionview

In my storyboard I have a tableview and in the tableview cell I've put a UICollectionview , My uicollectionview functions are defined in my table view class , as you can see at the end of my question :

but I have error in Perform Segue line , This is my error :
Use of unresolved identifier 'performSegue'
how can I set a perform segue correctly here ? cause my tableview class is not a UIViewController class ☹️

```
   class tableviewcell: UITableViewCell,UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.collectionView.delegate = self
    self.collectionView.dataSource = self
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
 return 2
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellID", for: indexPath) as! collectionViewCell
    cell.title.text = "test"
    return cell
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueID", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: `performSegue` is a method for view controllers, not a `UITableView` subclass. Either set the VC as the delegate and data source, or get a reference to the VC from the `UITableViewCell` and use `performSegue` on it.

Comment: This answer has some points - better to use delegation. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26467882/8289095

Comment: You can use Delegate pattern or Closure to tell the UIViewController to perform the segue.