# Swift present view without segue with delegate

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have a table view with buttons on programmatically generated cells to create a menu for my app, but I want to make the button on each cell go to a different view controller. This is the code to generate the cells.

```
import UIKit


class MenuViewController: UIViewController, SwitchView {
    let titles: [String] = ["Previous Issues", "Bookmarks", "Settings", "Website", "About"]
    let images: [UIImage] = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "newspaper.png"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "bookmark-outline.png"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "settings.png"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "outside-page.png"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "info.png")]
    var menuItems: [menuItem] = []
    public var index: Int = 0



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    menuItems = createMenu()
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
}

func switchView(index: Int){
    NSLog("THIS CODE IS RUNNING")
    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Settings")
    self.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func createMenu() -> [menuItem]{
    var index: Int = 0
    for (i,image) in zip(titles, images) {
        menuItems.append(menuItem(labelText: i, picture: image, index: index))
        index += 1
    }
    return menuItems
}

}

extension MenuViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITabBarDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return menuItems.count
    }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        tableView.rowHeight = 90
        tableView.separatorStyle = .singleLine
        let item = menuItems[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MenuCell") as! MenuCell
        cell.setAttributes(item: item)
        return cell
    }
}
```

This is my MenuCell code

```
import UIKit

protocol SwitchView {
    func switchView(index: Int)
}

class MenuCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var picture: UIImageView!
var index: Int = 0
var delegate: SwitchView?

func setAttributes(item: menuItem) {
    label.text = item.labelText
    picture.image = item.picture
    index = item.index
}

@IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {
    delegate?.switchView(index: index)
    NSLog("BUTTON")
}

}
```

The code runs fine with no errors, but when I click on the buttons of my table, the switchView() method inside my MenuViewController class is not running, but the button code is. Am I missing something?

P.S the code for selecting which view controller gets presented is not running, at this point, I am just trying to get the Settings view controller to be presented when I press the button on the MenuCell.

Comment: The error is because you're attempting to present the view from a ViewController that is not showing (that is, one you're creating but not showing). You'll need to call present on the MenuViewController that is showing the table. Best way is to use delegation, i.e. do not create a direct reference to the VC but use a delegate. See this answer for help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26467606/how-to-reference-controller-from-a-uitableviewcell-class-in-swift

Comment: Thanks for your help! Just tried presenting the new view inside the MenuViewController, but I just got " 'Application tried to present modally an active controller " error... @ChrisShaw

Comment: You don't show the code for `PreviousIssue`, `Bookmarks` etc types. Are they view controllers (presumably so if using `.present()`)? If so, you'll need to create them properly (from storyboards?) - not just instantiate them. Remember: every time you call an init function (e.g. `PreviousIssue()`) you are creating a **new** object, not just referencing an existing object. Consider whether blindly creating five new VC instances which may not all be used is a sensible strategy (hint: it isn't).

Comment: I have classes for PreviousIssue, Bookmarks, etc.. but they're all empty. Do they need to have something in them? What would be a more efficient way to do this? @ChrisShaw

Comment: Well, if you want to present a new view controller then they'll need to have view controller code (by extending UIViewController). It sounds like you're jumping in a bit here. Try stepping back and following a tutorial on UIStoryboards and transitions. Ray Wenderlich has good examples of using a storyboard.

Comment: @ChrisShaw they inherit the UIViewController class and are connected to view controllers in the storyboard. But thats all they need to do right?

Comment: If they're on storyboards, follow this: let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "newViewController") as! NewViewController
        self.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: thanks so much. this is exactly what i needed. Ill create delegates to send the data