# Swift: UIlabel text property gets changed but the displayed value in the UI doesn't change

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uilabel, tvos

When a user clicks on a collection view item, I want to change the UILabelView text property:

```
// This is another viewController not the one containing the label
// Handle collectionViewItem selection
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("INSIDE TableViewCell2.collectionView 3")
    TabsBarController.sharedInstance.testTitle = "UILabelText"
    print("didSelectItem\(indexPath)")
}
```

Once it's set, I try to update it here:

```
  class TabsBarController: UIViewController {
    static let sharedInstance = TabsBarController()
    var movieTitle:  UILabel? = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300.00, height: 30.00));
    var testTitle: String? = nil {
        didSet {
            print("testTitle.didSet: ",testTitle!) // logs the correct text
            movieTitle?.text = testTitle
            print(" movieTitle?.text : ", movieTitle?.text ) // logs the correct text
        }
    }
}
```

The problem here is that even though `movieTitle?.text`, in the UI, the `movieTitle` `UILabel` doesn't change.
I've read many answers to similar question, and all of them point to using the main thread, so I added this:

```
 class TabsBarController: UIViewController {
        static let sharedInstance = TabsBarController()
        var movieTitle:  UILabel? = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300.00, height: 30.00));
        var testTitle: String? = nil {
            didSet {
                // I added this but still nothing changed.
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    // Run UI Updates
                    print("testTitle.didSet: ",testTitle!) // logs the correct text
                    movieTitle?.text = testTitle
                    print(" movieTitle?.text : ", movieTitle?.text ) // logs the correct text
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
```

But, still the UI doesn't get updated. Any idea why is this happening and how to solve it?

**NOTE:** This is the hierarchy :
The hierarchy is like this TabsBarViewController-> MoviesViewController -> UITableView->UitableViewCell->CollectionView

Comment: Are you sure that the presented `TabsBarController` (the one you see on screen) is THE SAME INSTANCE as the one returned by `static let sharedInstance = TabsBarController()`?

Comment: I thought that's the case. How can I be sure?

Comment: I don't know your app architecture, but if you do `print(TabsBarController.sharedInstance)`, and if you use the Debug View Hierarchy (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015022-CH9-SW2) find the TabsBar you see on screen, and check its address)

Comment: Okay, thanks. But any suggestion as to how target the actual TabsBarController instance that's displayed?

Comment: It really depends on your app UI architecture. Currently, I can't guess. But you might be able to get from a `self.parent` in a UIViewController, it might be the TabsBarController you want. But again, it's lacking info on your ViewController logic. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621362-parent

Comment: Okay thanks for the tips.

Comment: A guess: `TabsBarController.sharedInstance.testTitle = "UILabelText"` => `if let tabsController = self.parent as? TabsBarController { print("parent is tabbar"); tansController = "UILabelText" } else { print("parent is not a TabsBarController, need more digging");}` might do the trick.

Comment: FYI the collectionView is written in another viewController.

Comment: If there's another way of setting testTitle without using a shared instance let me know

Comment: I tried this and I thought it should work. Since I am instantiating the actual tabsViewController that's displayed but it didn't:  let vc: TabsBarController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabsBarController") as! TabsBarController
        vc.testTitle = "test"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223366/discussion-between-larme-and-ahmed-ghrib).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the project hierarchy, I had to follow the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26467606/how-to-reference-uitableviewcontroller-from-a-uitableviewcell-class/26467781#26467781) in order to be able to access the `UITabsBarController` `testTitle` property from inside the `tableViewCell`.
Just one caveat, I had to do this casting:

```
 // Handle collectionViewItem selection
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("INSIDE TableViewCell2.collectionView 3")
   
          if let vc2 =  self.viewController?.parent as? TabsBarController {
             vc2.testTitle = "THIS WILL DEFINITELY ABSOLUTELY WORK I DONT CARE"
        }
        print("didSelectItem\(indexPath)")
    }
```

Comment: that was a mistake.